# React list and keys, missing object properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In this [react tutorial](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/the-road-to-learn-react/hacker-stories/tree/2021/Callback-Handler-in-JSX?file=/src/App.js), the author uses a snippet of code, starting on line 61:

```js
const List = (props) => (
  <ul>
    {props.list.map((item) => (
      <Item key={item.objectID} item={item} />
    ))}
  </ul>
);
```

This function is called from within the const, App, `<List list={stories} />` on line 35. And lastly, stories is an object:

```js
const stories = [
    {
      title: 'React',
      url: 'https://reactjs.org/',
      author: 'Jordan Walke',
      num_comments: 3,
      points: 4,
      objectID: 0,
    },
    {
      title: 'Redux',
      url: 'https://redux.js.org/',
      author: 'Dan Abramov, Andrew Clark',
      num_comments: 2,
      points: 5,
      objectID: 1,
    },
  ];
```

I'm confused regarding line 61, specifically the code `props.list.map`. From the object, stories, there is no list attribute. However, in line 35, `<List list={stories} />` seems to imply that stories will be referenced by the key, list.

My questions are:

1. What's going on here?
2. Why would this extra complexity be beneficial (globally speaking beyond the context of this code)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prop is named `list`, but the value of that prop is being filled by the `stories` const. The reason you might do that is to make your `List` component generic and flexible.

If you wanted to reuse `List` for some other purpose, but had to pass it a prop named `stories` when you were actually passing it classes or some other type of list, it would be confusing.

In your case, just understand that `props.list` is actually `stories` here.

Comment: In your second sentence/paragraph, w/o the `list` name, could any arbitrary object be supplied, it just need be referenced as stories? Or does the `list=` syntax allow for any arbitrary object to be passed?

Comment: A component determines the names of the props it accepts. So if the `List` function uses `props.something`, then anything that uses `List` is now required to name the prop `something` (`<List something={stories} />`). Any data may be provided as the value, that's the responsibility of the *user* of the component

Answer (score 1):

Given any `<Component prop={value} />`, you access `value` with `prop`:

```js
function Component(props) {
    props.prop; // get value :O
}
```

Many people use destructuring because it is easier to read:

```js
function Component({ prop }) {
    prop; // get value too :O
}
```

And also if you have an object of props for a component, you can spread them:

```js
const theProps = { prop: 42 };

return <Component {...theProps} /> // same as <Component prop={theProps.prop} />
```

Furthermore, you don't have to destructure every prop, you can collect the rest into an object to be used normally:

```js
function Component({ importantProp, ...notAsImportant }) {
    importantProp; // easy access and to use

    notAsImportant.prop; // you can still get the other props normally
}
```